# Text from Quillpad not printed using PdfPCell

Tags: c#, itext

I was wondering why it is happening. [Quillpad](http://quillpad.com) is an online tool for writing text in several Indian languages. It generates the Unicode string which can be used anywhere. I tried using the following statements -

```
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell r1c2 = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell(new iTextSharp.text.Phrase("वाहन बेचने वाले का नाम एवं पता", pdfHindiFont));
r1c2.HorizontalAlignment = iTextSharp.text.Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
IA_table.AddCell(r1c2);
```

where IA_table is object of PdfPTable and pdfHindiFont is object of Font with Arial font which then i changed to Mangal font (unicode)

```
iTextSharp.text.Font pdfHindiFont = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont("Mangal", 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);
```

But when PDF is generated nothing is printed.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The font might not be found. To test that put some normal string in that cell and use a common font (or no font parameter at all) - does the content get rendered then?
Where did you put that font in filesystem? Did you register the font or the directory using FontFactory.RegisterDirectory?

Comment: That's the Unicode string. Normal text is rendered properly, even custom font text appears properly as well.